# Solution for linearly dependant linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem asks me to find the eigenvectors of the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2  & 2 &-3\\  2&2&3\\-3&3&3\end{pmatrix}$ coressponding to the eigenvectors $4$ and $6$. Now I do know how to solve this, that is by finding the vector $\mathbf x$ such that $A\mathbf x=4\mathbf x$, thus we imemdiately must have:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-2&2&-3 \\ 2 &-2 &3 \\ -3 &3&-1\end{pmatrix}\mathbf x=\mathbf 0,$$obviously the determinant for the matrix above is $0$ and it's easy to see that the first and second rows are basically the exact same thing, so we can just want to evaluate the equation $$\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 2 &-3\\-3&3&-1 \end{pmatrix}\mathbf x =\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix},$$ which is really easy to do and we get $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ as an eigenvector, my question is that when I looked at the answers they had simply said that the the eigenvector is $$\begin{vmatrix}i &j&k\\-2&2&-3\\-3&3&-1 \end{vmatrix}.$$ How is it that they just used this determinant to solve this? Is this a method to solve all linearly dependant equations?.

Comment: Just use Gaussian elimination. It does not need the fact that the equations are linearly dependent or independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that any solution to the equation 
$$
\pmatrix{-2&2&-3\\-3&3&-1}\mathbf x = 0
$$
is perpendicular to the vectors $(-2,2,-3)$ and $(-3,3,-1)$.  You could always find a solution to this matrix equation in the usual way.  However, we could use the *cross-product* and note that
$$
\mathbf x = (-2,2,-3) \times (-3,3,-1)
$$
will be perpendicular to both $(-2,2,-3)$ and $(-3,3,-1)$, and so will be a non-zero solution to our matrix equation. That is what they have done here.

This is a method that will only work for solving $A\mathbf x = 0$ when $A$ is a $2 \times 3$ matrix, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Actually, we could extend this determinant method to work whenever $A$ is $(n-1) \times n$. However, when $n$ is large, row-reduction tends to be much easier than computing determinants.